# Can I auto-update a Chrome extension from the Store if I downloaded it manually as a local folder?

Tags: google-chrome

I had an extension installed from store. I changed one file localy and to test it, i did a copy of extension folder and uploaded in in Developer mode. It replaced my official extension. If i go to store and open it, i still see it as installed. But i cant update it from Store because it's local now. Can i make it official again and update to online (Store version) without deleting it? I have settings stored here.

I tried to restore original version from original folder, but it's still local version.

Comment: Just copy the settings somewhere and put them back later. You can find them in the relevant `Extension State` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Set new destination of ext from original folder. Copied new version of ext from another browser to original folder with deletion of older version. Restarted. It kept settings and replaced with online version.